# SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, session, request, screen-scraping

i have a syntax error in my code i dont no understand 
i need help for this I do not see my error

```
      headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537)'}
      session = requests.Session()
      response = session.get(olinks, headers=headers)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
      oname = soup.find("title")
      if oname.text.find('Saison') >= 0:
          regexp = r'(.*?\s+-\s+S)aison\s+(\d+)\s+\xc9.*?(\d+)(.*)'
          subst = "{title} {season:02d} Ep {episode}"
      else:
          regexp = r'(.*?\s+-)(\s+)\xc9.*?(\d+)(.*)'
          subst = "{title} Ep {episode}"
      oname_cleanedup = re.sub(regexp, 
                         lambda m: subst.format(title=m.group(1), season=int(m.group(2)) if m.group(2).find(" ")==-1 else "", episode=m.group(3))
             oname.text)
```

sorry

```
File "start.py", line 41
    oname.text)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why is the second line indented but not the first? Can you add the actual error to your question?

Comment: is the real error edit  I am to tire ... loll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma `,` at the end of the line beginning with `lambda`. If you were to look at the full text of the syntax error, it will tell you exactly where it occured, so start looking just before it to find out what's wrong or missing.

Comment: @parcal yes, I see you edited your question, but the answer is still the same - you're missing a comma at the very end of the line that starts with `lambda`. Add that and your code will run.

Comment: ty lol is an evidence